# Python socket: Errno 9 Bad file descriptor when recv

Tags: python, sockets

My problem is like this. I would need to create a client program for quick trial that can send out some commands and listen to data(after which I would need to parse it) from the same socket. So I have created two threads(one to issue command (not shown here), the other to listen to data) to handle this after I created the sockets and connect out to the server. Server is written in other langauges.

- As the same socket is to be used, I  thought that the socket should be set to be unblocking
- the socket after creation is send to the thread as an arguement.

I tried to run the python program. And there is a problem of `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`. I have narrowed down the problem. It got to do with the recv function.

Most of the solution down in the forum seem to point to socket closure as the main problem but i really could not see how since the socket closure was placed out of while loop.

So need somebody help to point to the problem. And here is my code (as below)

```
import socket
import errno
import sys
import threading

HOST = "192.168.50.35"
PORT = 2356            


def listener(sock, q):
    print("status thread created")

    while q != True:
        try:
            data = sock.recv(1024)
        except socket.error as socketerr:
            if socketerr == errno.EAGAIN or socketerr == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                sleep(1)
                print('Data is unavailable')
                continue
            else:
                print(socketerr)
                sys.exit(1)
        else:
            print(f" new {data!r} recieved")

            ### processed data
            ### some processing set but not shown here
            continue
    sock.close()
    
def connect():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        try:
            s.connect((HOST, PORT))        
            s.setblocking(0)
            s.settimeout(1)                
        
        except socket.error as socketerr:
            print("Error: ", socketerr)    

    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_machine_info()
    q = False      
    s = connect()

    print("socket created")

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=status, args=(s,q))
    t1.daemon = False
    t1.start()
```

Comment: Your `connect` method uses a context manager (i.e. a `with` statement) to manage the socket. As soon as control exits the `with` statement the socket is closed. See [socket objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-objects): "Changed in version 3.2: Support for the context manager protocol was added. Exiting the context manager is equivalent to calling close()."

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: Thanks it certainly solve my problem... when i changed it to an instantiation